# Detect vowels and consonants?

Tags: signals, signal-processing, speech-recognition, speech-synthesis

I'm working on the speech signal processing area and I want to detect and time tag vowels and consonants from a audio file.

I'd like something such as (just and example, not sure how it works):

Using the word **Done**: **D** [0-3 ms], **o** [4-7 ms], **n** [8-11 ms], and **e** [12-13 ms].

I think I'm facing somehow a classificaion problem, I thought about using *Support Vector Machines* or *Hidden Markov Models* or *Reccurant Neural Networks*.

Any suggestions on how I should do it, the vowel or consonant detection, the time tagging.

Probably I'll use MATLAB. What do you think?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't cross post on multiple sites! You asked verbatim the same on signals. SE.

Comment: This is a verbatim cross post within shortest time and should be closed.

Comment: for reference: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/50948/detect-classify-vowels-and-consonants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case, u prefer using HMM, my suggestion using HTK (Hidden markov toolkit) there is a precise/detail tutorial, but it's in C (ANSI). Using HMM u must train HMM first (supervised), of course u need complete phonems/tag labeled train/examples. Finally what you need to do is what called phonems recognition to recognize others voice/test audio. After that, The duration of each recognized phonems/tag can be  calculated after recognized by HTK.

Comment: About the train part, it should be single worlds, entire sequences or both?

Comment: both since HTK support continuous word. HTK treats (SILENCE) as a special phonem/subword-model. I mean a single hmm model can be reserved for silence (interword pause) as u can see in its tutorial.